# Array size not static?

Tags: c++, arrays

can someone please explain to me why this works. I thought arrays were static and couldn't expand, this piece of code defies my prior knowledge.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int test[10];
    int e = 14;

for(int i = 0; i < e; i++){
    test[i] = i;
    cout << "  " << test[i];
    }
return 0;
}
```

This code outputs this:
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13

So basically this program uses array spaces that shouldn't exist.
Tried setting 'e' as 15, doesn't work.

Comment: Just FYI: On my system your code stops after printing the number 10 and the value of `e` is 10 after the loop.

Comment: It doesn't work. It just hasn't noticed yet that it's dead already.. ;-)

Comment: You might be interested in checking std::array introduced in C++11. The [] operator still does not do bounds checking. But you always can always the function at to do the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The array's size *is* fixed, it is not expanding, and going beyond its bounds is undefined behaviour. What you observed is one possible outcome of undefined behaviour (UB). You were unlucky that in this case the UB suggests a pattern consistent with the array expanding.

Comment: the worst kind of undefined behavior. ie the code works and seems to do the right thing, check it it, job done, go home. Months later things inexplicably go bang in the middle of the night at a critical customer site

Comment: Search the web for "Buffer overrun attack".

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour. You still have only 10 ints allocated legally. Though it seems to work in this case, your program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

You basically write beyond the boundary of the memory allocated by your array, but C (and C++) is compiled directly to machine code (an opposite to "managed" code executed by virtual machine, like Java or .NET), so there is nothing between your program and OS which will verify if you access memory you have not explicitly asked for. Memory is allocated in some chunks, when a process is requesting some portion of memory from OS, it does not get that precise number of bytes, but may get slightly more. In your case instead of 40 bytes you got 56. Why you did not get 60 - depends on OS memory allocation and verification mechanism. What was the symptom of not working when e was set to 15 - program crash?

Answer (score 1):

It is a runtime error and not a compilation error.  The reason is fails at 15 and not 14 is of because once you reach position 15 you have hit memory that has been allocated to another pointer or application.  It just so happens that indexes 11, 12 ,13 and 14 are contiguous memory locations that have not yet been malloc'ed

Comment: This is C++, not C. Use C++ terms like allocate instead of malloc. :)

Comment: The array is not allocated on the heap.